# How to check if column exists in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I want to check if the column exist or not, I bind the data from a database to the `DataGridView` and I added link button as a column along with the `DataGridView`. I used the following code in the button click event.

```
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter dadatagrid1 =
    new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Stocktransferlocation", con);
DataSet dsdatagrid1 = new DataSet();
dadatagrid1.Fill(dsdatagrid1);
dataGridView_stocktransferlist.DataSource = dsdatagrid1.Tables[0];
con.Close();

DataGridViewLinkColumn btn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
dataGridView_stocktransferlist.Columns.Add(btn);
btn.HeaderText = "Click";
btn.Text = "Click Here";
btn.Name = "btn";
btn.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
```

Here my problem: if I click add button the data is saved and click link is appearing. If I click next time click appears 2 times.

I just want to check if the column exists in the datagrid. I tried

```
if (dataGridView_stocktransferlist.Columns.Contains("Click") == true)
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 13):

The `Contains` method fails because the column name is **'btn'** and not **'Click'**.

As you can see on the [`DataGridViewLinkColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx) documentation, is the property `Name` that defines the column name the `Contains` method works on.

So your code should be

```
if (dataGridView_stocktransferlist.Columns.Contains("btn") == true
{
    .....
}
```

but I suggest to give a more meaningful name to your button like 'btnLinkForEdit' and change the if accordingly.

Comment: i used ur code, but still its same

Answer (score 0):

You should check as follows:

```
if (dataGridView_stocktransferlist.Columns.Contains("btn"))
{
  //your code
}
```